# 2D array and method calling

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

So, I'm creating this minesweeper game and I am confused with 2 of my methods which one, will initialize the array with a certain character and one method will actually print the game. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    System.out.println("Welcome to Mine Sweeper!");

    a = promptUser(in, "What width of map would you like (3 - 20):", 3, 20);
    b = promptUser(in, "What height of map would you like (3 - 20):", 3, 20);

    eraseMap(new char[b][a]);
    simplePrintMap(new char[b][a]);
}

public static int promptUser(Scanner in, String prompt, int min, int max) {

    int userInput;
    System.out.println(prompt);
    userInput = in.nextInt();

    while (userInput < min || userInput > max) {
        System.out.println("Expected a number from 3 to 20.");
        userInput = in.nextInt();
    }
    return userInput;
}

public static void eraseMap(char[][] map) {

    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; ++j) {
            map[i][j] = (Config.UNSWEPT);

        }
    }
    return;
}

public static void simplePrintMap(char[][] map) {

    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map[i].length; ++j) {
            System.out.print(map[b][a] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return;
}
```

The methods that are in question is eraseMap and simplePrintMap. eraseMap is supposed to initialize the array with "." and simplePrintMap is supposed to actually print the array. So if i input 3 and 4, it will print periods will a width of 3 and height of 4.

(each period separated by space).

Comment: What is the problem? What do you expect and what do you actually get for a given input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A)** You create 2 seperate `map`s. You perform the erase on the first, then throw it all away, create a new `map` and print that. Which, of course, is empty.

Try creating one `map` and work on it:

```
char[][] map = new char[b][a]
eraseMap(map);
simplePrintMap(map);
```

**B)** in the print method, you use the wrong indices:

```
System.out.print(map[b][a] + " ");
```

change these to

```
System.out.print(map[i][j] + " ");
```

**C)** not an error, just a hint: you don't need `return;` at the end of `void` methods.